# Importing Modules Between Python Files

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver

I have a doubt ...

I have this little selenium code called (test.py) and my queue file called (worker.py). The file (test.py) and (worker.py) are in the same folder. I import my code (test.py) to (worker.py) the queue returns me result, but when it sends information to (test.py) it returns me error

test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
def run():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elem.send_keys('{}'.format(data['name']))
run()
```

this is just a small part of my code.

worker.py

```
import pika
import json
def worker(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Worker received a job")
    print("\tBody: %r" % body)
try:
    data = json.loads(body)
    print('\tData: {}'.format(data['name'].upper()))
    print('\tWorking...')
    import test         ##### code (test.py)
```

this is the error message that returns me.

```
 global name 'data' is not defined
```

Can someone help me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change test.py:

```
def run(data):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elem.send_keys('{}'.format(data['name']))
```

Change worker.py:

```
try:
    data = json.loads(body)
    print('\tData: {}'.format(data['name'].upper()))
    print('\tWorking...')
    from test import run
    run(data)
```

Comment: if I had for example

def run (data):
      def__init __ (self):
       self.driver = webdriver.Firefox ()
       self.driver.get('https://www.google.com')
       elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name ('q')
       elem.send_keys ('{}'. formart (data ['name']))  would it be the same thing ??